# What does it mean by degree $n \geq 2$?

Tags: polynomials

As the title said, and full question is such as below;

A polynomial $m(x)$ to the degree $n \geq 2$ has a remainder of $−4$ when it is divided by $(x+3)$ and a remainder of $1$ when it is divided by $(4x-1)$. Find the remainder when $m(x)$ is divided by $(x+3)(4x-1)$.

Comment: This means that the degree of $m$ has degree greater than or equal to $2$. So, this means $m(x)$ looks like $m(x) = a_0 + a_1x + ... + a_nx^n$ where $a_n \neq 0$ and $n \geq 2$.

Answer (score 0):

The degree of the polynomial is the highest power, so the fact that the degree is greater than $2$, the division algorithm for polynomials says that there is some $q(x),r(x)$ where $\deg r(x)<1$(so $r(x)$ is a constant) such that $m(x)=(x+3)q(x)+r(x)=(x+3)q(x)-4$, so $m(-3)=-4$. Similarly, we have that $m(x)=(4x-1)p(x)+1$ for some polynomial $p(x)$, so $m(\frac{1}{4})=1$.

Now if we do the division algorithm with $(x+3)(4x-1)$, we have that $m(x)=(x+3)(4x-1)l(x)+s(x)$ for some $l(x)$ and $\deg s(x)<2$. Now we have that $m(-3)=s(-3)=-4$ and $m(\frac{1}{4})=s(\frac{1}{4})=1$. Thus, we have that $s(x)=ax+b$, so we wish to solve for $a$ and $b$, and we get that $s(-3)=-3a+b=-4$ and $s(\frac{1}{4})=\frac{a}{4}+b=1$, or $a+4b=4$. Solving this system, we find that $a=\frac{20}{13}$, $b=\frac{8}{13}$